# Is this how logical operations and a computer work?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I was watching [this video](http://youtu.be/WIDzNyfVVg0?t=5m8s) and trying to figure out how a computer really works. At the start the following diagram appears:

[image: AND gate]

Basically what I understand is that in order to form a logical output like AND, there is a need to have a combination of transistors in order to create a frequency (signal?) that has the value of an AND. Is this right?

Please don't go too rough or too theoretical on me, as it is the first electronics video that I've seen and I don't have the minimal understanding of electronic terms or knowledge of electronics to understand hardcore processes.

Comment: I suspect you may have been a little mislead by the label F on the output in the AND gate illustration. The F in this case doesn't mean "Frequency" but more likely "Function (of the two inputs)". The label can of course be anything but is usually not O (for output) because that could be easily misread as 0 (for zero).

Answer (score 3):

Questions and answers need to use the correct words, otherwise they are meaningless (or worse: misleading).

A logical gate CAN be made from transistors. There are various other possibilities, from practical ones that have been used historically (relays, vacuum tubes) to esoteric ones (mechanical contraptions, cleverly formed molecules).

An AND gate produces at its output a signal level that is the AND function of its two (or more) inputs. The AND function (and the AND gate) are mathematical constructs. A real-world device can implement an AND gate, which means that it (within certain limitations) behaves according to the mathematical AND gate model.

Answer (score 0):

Switches are made with CMOS transmission gates using complementary devices.  The basic logic of your AND gate is correct, but your  output is like a SPST switch with pull-up, which also has an inherent load capacitance, which is slower.  Inversion is normal for complementary drivers using gate in and drain output.

This is a SPDT inverter switch which uses the C in CMOS to drive hi or Low out with low resistance to the supply voltage, 0V or V+.

[image]So simple gates are NOR, NAND, while OR, AND needs an extra complementary inverter output stage, which adds more delay, but less delay than your open switch with a pull-up resistor.  Delay is increased by the RC time constant of the load

They use complementary drivers to Switch hi and low with the same low resistance to Vcc and gnd, like a SPDT switch. Memory is also made with NOR or NAND gate pairs to form a latch or a Flip Flop cell.
[image][image]

The speed is limited by the longest chain of gates or switches and smaller switch capacitance and lower resistance improves the speed by reducing the junction size and optimizing the channel physics for the lowest resistance possible with a low gate voltage.